# Typescript return type changes with async keyword

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

This seems really strange to me.

I have a function to count documents from a collection

```
async getDocCount(): Promise<number> {
   return MyModel.countDocuments({});
}
```

All good. But there's no reason to have `async` when you are returning a Promise. So I remove `async` and typescript complains. I hover over the return type and it is now something crazy like

```
mongoose.QueryWithHelpers<number, mongoose.Document<mongoose.Types.ObjectId, BeAnObject, any> & MyModel & IObjectWithTypegooseFunction & {
    ...;
}, BeAnObject, DocumentType<...>>
```

What's going on here? Why does removing `async` affect the return type?

Answer (score 1):

`MyModel.countDocuments({})` returns a `Query`, and [*"Queries are not promises"*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises).

They *are* thenable so you can `await` them, but if you want a proper promise, you need to call `exec()` on it:

```
return MyModel.countDocuments({}).exec();
```

Although I'm not sure if that will yield the proper return type (`Promise<number>`) for TS, you may have to use `return await MyModel.countDocuments({})` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `async` *always* makes the function return a `Promise`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> ## Return value
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

If your function compiled with `async`, then that means `MyModel.countDocuments({})` returns something compatible with `number`, *not* `Promise<number>`, and then the `async` keyword automatically added the `Promise` part itself.

I'm not familiar with Mongoose, so I can't speak to the keyboard smash of a type signature that the library seems to be returning. But Typescript has some very powerful rules for what types are compatible with what other types, so it's very possible that that complicated Mongoose type is actually compatible with `number`.

I do challenge your assertion that the `countDocuments` function returns a promise to begin with, though, as Typescript seems to be indicating the opposite in its error.

Comment: It does not return a typical Promise. It returns a class with some kind of magic async thing `[Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<DocType>;`.  See this image https://imgur.com/atEVkYm

Comment: So it still makes me wonder how this works